# After UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication, how to put claims from Security Token into Controller.User (Current HttpContext) that are in OwinConext.User?

Tags: owin, claims-based-identity, httpcontext, asp.net-mvc-5.2, openid-connect

I have VS2013 MVC5 project with *Individual User Accounts*. I modified `Startup {Configuration(IAppBuilder app)}` so that `UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication` is the only allowed authentication.

Users can register in the AspNetIdentity DB using the out of the box MVC project template plumbing. After registration, Users login with OIDC.

The OpenID Connect STS (IdentityServer3 with AspNetIdentity) returns a security token with claims and roles. These claims are available from the authenticated `ClaimsPrincipal`in the `Request.GetOwinContext().Authentication.User`.

However these claims are missing from the `Controller.User` (Current HTTP Request context).

Is it a good thing to make the two `ClaimsPrincipal` match?

QUESTION: If so how and ***where*** do I do that? I'm not an expert and wonder what about `OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications.SecurityTokenValidated` or 
`Application_PostAuthenticateRequest`?

I realize this is a side-effect of mixing MVC5 `System.Web` with OWIN middleware for OpenIdConnect, rather than the default MVC5 project authentication middleware.

Comment: I'm glad to see you've got OIDC working with IdentityServer3 and AspNetIdentity. I'm struggling to get mine working with an error that the client is unknown or unauthorized.  I posted my question here:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29607527 Any chance you can look and advise?

Answer (score 1):

if you are working with ASP.NET 4.6 and Katana 3.x you should be able to access the claims you want from ClaimsPrincipal.Current.

See the comment below

Comment: thank you; yes I know ClaimsPrincipal.Current.  My question really wants to ask where in the pipeline should that be done?  I proposed inserting code into one of two methods (named above) or somewhere else; where should I put it?

Comment: I am not sure I am following. If ClaimsPrincipal.Current contains the claims you need, and ClaimsPrincipal.Current is available in the code scope in whihc you want to consume those values, why do you want to copy them elsewhere as well?

Comment: As I have a MVC app, for convenience, it is useful if the Controller.User has information from the claims initialized by the Open ID Connect. E.g. the VS MVC template code uses the Controller.User. It's just that simple.

Comment: The thing I am not following is - if the claims are already available in ClaimsPrincipal.Current, when you need to access those values you can simply go through it. If you want to go through Controller.User, you still need to write values accessor code (this time against Controller.User)  AND you have to write code for making the deep copy of all the claims from the ClaimsPrincipal to Controller.User. And - the deep copy code has to be executed at every request. If you really want to do it: placing it in SecurityTokenValidated is more flexible.

Comment: thank you for the insightful comment. I marked your answer as accepted and added a line in your answer referring to your previous comment.